# No numbering solution environment when ams style is enabled (beamer)

Tags: beamer, numbering, counters

I would like still using numeration for `theorem`, `definition` except only for `solution when ams style is enabled. Please any hint.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{theorem}
        Nice proposition.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{solution}
        Foo.
    \end{solution}

    \begin{example}
        Baz.
    \end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The desired out will be

```
Theorem 1
Solution
Example 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick hack, you could use a normal beamer `block` for the solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]

\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}
\renewenvironment<>{solution}{\begin{block}#1{Solution}\itshape}{\end{block}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{theorem}
        Nice proposition.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{solution}
        Foo.
    \end{solution}

    \begin{example}
        Baz.
    \end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot
`\renewenvironment<>{solution}{\begin{block}#1{\translate{Solution}}\itshape}{\end{block}}`

Comment: @Oromion You're welcome!